# How to set different seed for each run in lapply

Tags: r, lapply, random-seed

I wrote a function and package it to lapply. Basically, this is a iteration process and I need different result from each run. And if I set a seed in the function, I would get totally the same results.

Thus, how can I transfer different seed each run to lapply because this is not like for loop which I can add 1 to the current 'seed' and make it totally reproducible.

```
iter.times <- 50 # iteration time

surv_lasso <- function(surv.obj = NULL, expr.obj = NULL, nfolds = NULL, alpha = 1, family = "cox") {

  # I want to set a different seed here for each run in lapply, but I have no idea how to handle that.

 # set.seed(888) # this is not right because I would get totally the same lasso_fea each run in lapply

  cvfit = cv.glmnet(x = t(as.matrix(expr.obj)), 
                    y = surv.obj, 
                    nfolds = nfolds, # 10-fold CV
                    alpha = alpha, 
                    family = family) 

  # optimal lambda
  myCoefs <- coef(cvfit, s="lambda.min");
  lasso_fea <- myCoefs@Dimnames[[1]][which(myCoefs != 0 )]
}

lapply(1:iter.times,surv_lasso, surv.obj = surv, expr.obj = surv.expr, nfolds = 10) # I think I should put a paramter to transfer different seed to surv_lasso function, but how to realize it.
```

Comment: What's the problem with just setting a single seed just before the `lapply`?

Comment: OMG, how stupid I am. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the seed position for each run in `lapply` with a custom list of seeds, e.g.

```
list.of.seeds <- 1:50

lapply(1:50, function(x){
  set.seed(list.of.seeds[x])
  sample(1:10, 1)})
```

Comment: Thanks but I have fixed this by just setting a single seed just before the lapply